# Use of vector pushback with "temp" struct in one line (if possible)

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have the following code (butchered to make it small and specific):

```
struct myType_t
{
    int a;
    string str;
};
typedef vector<myType_t> dataVect_t; // Just for ease of use

...main(...)
{
    dataVect_t myData;
    myData.push_back((myType_t) {1, "test"}); // THIS IS THE LINE IN QUESTION!
}
```

**EDIT:** sorry, this is corrected to creating an instance of myType_t (not dataVect_t)

I want to pushback an instance of intStringPairVect_t into the vector, but I dont really want to create a variable just to do this. What I am doing seems to compile, but I am not 100% convinced it is correct... any pointers (no pun intended) here?

Comment: Start by using `push_back` rather than `pushback`. If that compiles, you have a rather odd standard library. Why you're casting to a vector-type rather just using a `myType_t` I'm still not clear on your intent, but as-written it won't compile even with fixing the push_back: `No matching constructor for initialization of 'dataVect_t' (aka 'vector<myType_t>')`

Comment: Sorry, that is what I meant, I hand typed it to make it small... corrected :)

Comment: You should avoid using C-style casts in C++, especially when type is one word

Comment: Good point, it was not my intention to cast it, I meant to be constructing and initialising a temp instance, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want this

```
myData.push_back( myType_t { 1, "test" });
                  ~~~~~~~~
```

It uses uniform initializer to make an object of `myType_t`.

---

If you're not using C++11, then you can define a constructor and do a same thing by `()`:

```
struct myType_t
{
    myType_t(int a, string str) : a(a), str(str){}
    int a;
    string str;
};

myData.push_back( myType_t ( 1, "test" ));
```

Comment: Thanks, is this the same, or is there a difference? - I assume this is actually constructing a temporary instance? (and mine is not?)

Comment: It's a temporary object. You're making those objects wrong: `(dataVect_t){1,"test"}` !

Comment: ahh... I am just casting "somthing" and not constructing anything really!, got it :)

Comment: hmm...infact this does not work for me... is this a c++11 feature? - I not using c++11...

Comment: @code_fodder 03x, but yes. Implement a constructor for `myType_t` and use `myData.push_back( myType_t(1,"test") )` instead if you're limited to non-03x c++.

Comment: @code_fodder: I've just added a non-C++11 way as WhozCraig mentioned.

Comment: Great, thanks both for that, its working nicely now :), I think I was getting confused between c++03x and pre-03x and getting confused. All working now

Answer (score 1):

I would do it with **emplace_back** instead of **push_back**:

```
struct myType_t
{
    myType_t(int a, string str) : a(a), str(str) { }
    int a;
    string str;
};
typedef vector<myType_t> dataVect_t; // Just for ease of use

main(...)
{
    dataVect_t myData;
    myData.emplace_back(1, "test"); // Emplacing directly.
}
```

This way you don't have to create a separate variable, and using emplace_back instead of push_back is more efficient, because that way the vector does not have to copy your myType_t instance.
(And in general I find it beneficial for types to have explicit constructors with the necessary parameters.)

If emplace_back is not supported by your compiler, you can still use this approach with push_back:

```
main(...)
{
    dataVect_t myData;
    myData.push_back(myType_t(1, "test")); // Push back by creating an object.
}
```

The only drawback of this solution is that the object is going to be copied when inserted into the vector.

Comment: Thanks for that, I just took a look into this, its a c++03x feature so I can't use it in my case, but +1 because that is exactly what I really wanted :)

Comment: Updated my answer with info on using this approach with push_back.

Comment: hmm... this one does not seem to compile. I get error: `no matching function call to std::vector...push_back(int, const char [3])`. I think the function is expecting a single data type...

Comment: Sorry, I copy pasted but forgot to edit, I corrected it now... You have to write out the name of the type if you use push_back, so it's the same as what M M. wrote.